# Overloading subscript operator in a C++/WinRT runtimeclass

Tags: c++, windows-runtime

I am new authoring C++/WinRT runtime classes, and I was requested to overload the subscript operator (**[ ]**) for a runtime class Parameter. The class Parameter contains an IMap<hstring, IInspectable> that stores a set of parameters indexed by the parameter name.

Here is the code:

```
namespace winrt::Parameter::implementation
{
    using namespace winrt;
    using namespace Windows::Foundation::Collections;

    struct Parameter : ParameterT<Parameter>
    {
    private:
        IMap<hstring, IInspectable> m_Parameters{ nullptr };

    public:
        Parameter() { m_Parameters = single_threaded_map<hstring, IInspectable>(); }
        ~Parameter() {};

        IInspectable& operator[](const hstring& key)
        {
            if (!m_Parameters.HasKey(key))
            {
                m_Parameters.Insert(key, {});
            }

            return m_Parameters.Lookup(key);
        }

        IInspectable const& operator[](const hstring& key) const
        {
            if (!m_Parameters.HasKey(key))
            {
                m_Parameters.Insert(key, {});
            }

            return m_Parameters.Lookup(key);
        }
    };
}

namespace winrt::Parameter::factory_implementation
{
    struct Parameter : ParameterT<Parameter, implementation::Parameter>
    {
    };
}
```

The code above compiles with no errors, but I get the below error when I try to consume the Parameter code in a UWP C# test App:

```
Parameter parameter = new Parameter();
const string V = "test";
parameter[V] = "any test value";
string test = parameter[V];
```

**Error CS0021  Cannot apply indexing with [ ] to an expression of type 'Parameter'**

Does anyone have any ideas on what I am missing here?

The problem seems to be with the C++/WinRT version because this other similar code using standard C++/17 works as expected.

```
class Parameter
{
private:
    std::map<std::string, std::any> m_Parameter{};

public:
    std::any& operator[](const std::string& name);
};

std::any& Parameter::operator[](const std::string& key)
{
    if (m_Parameter.find(key) == m_Parameter.end())
    {
        m_Parameter.insert({ key, {} });
    }

    return m_Parameter.at(key);
}

int main()
{
    Parameter parameter{};

    parameter["test"] = 'b';
    parameter["other test"] = std::string("other test value");

    std::cout << std::any_cast<std::string>(parameter["other test"]) << '\n';
    std::cout << std::any_cast<char>(parameter["test"]) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have two different `struct Parameter`s in you first code block (in two different namespaces). One defines an `operator[]`, the other does not.

Comment: C# doesn't see your C++ header file. It sees the metadata that was generated by your `idl` file. And your idl file doesn't have an overloaded `[]` operator for your Parameter class. (I know this because Windows Runtime idl files do not support operator overloading.)

Comment: Thanks @RaymondChen. Your comment should be an answer for the question so I could vote for it and close the thread.

Comment: Feel free to post and accept your own answer. That way, you can fill in the details to your satisfaction.